# List of Stocks by Sector

Tags: equities

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all stocks traded on the NYSE in a table that also includes what sector they are in? I want to look at some data using info both from the individual stock and from the sector but I cannot find a comprehensive list containing both pieces of information.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the *Mathematica* code below to make a list of stocks and sectors you can access here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkzpcnksvfygamp/nyse.xls

*Mathematica* uses curated data from Yahoo.  Items that lack sector information have been omitted.  The list may be incomplete but it might provide something for you to work with.

```
members = FinancialData["NYSE", "Members"];
names = If[SameQ[Head[#], FinancialData], "-", #] &@
     FinancialData[#, "Name"] & /@ members;
companies = If[SameQ[Head[#], FinancialData], "-", #] &@
     FinancialData[#, "Company"] & /@ members;
sectors = If[SameQ[Head[#], FinancialData], "-", #] &@
     FinancialData[#, "Sector"] & /@ members;
data = Transpose[{members, names, companies, sectors}];
data2 = DeleteCases[data, {_, _, _, Missing["NotAvailable"] | "-"}];
data3 = SortBy[data2, Last];
Export["nyse.xls", 
  Prepend[data3, {"Symbol", "Name", "Company", "Sector"}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [stock screener](http://finviz.com/screener.ashx) over at [FINVIZ](http://finviz.com). You can limit the results to NYSE listed stocks and can easily export to CSV using the "export" link at the bottom right of the table.

Bear in mind, industry/sector classifications are no uniform. You'll find different classification methods depending on where you look.

Answer (score 0):

As @Louis said, from Finviz's stock screener you can filter by exchange and sort column by sector.

```
>>> import urllib2 
>>> url = "http://www.finviz.com/export.ashx?v=111&f=exch_nyse&o=sector"
>>> file = open("tickers.txt",'wb')
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(url).readlines()
>>> for l in data:
... file.write(l)
>>> file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete list on the old NASDAQ website.

https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx